# How to take input and store it into a variable using PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python, input, pysimplegui

I'm trying to get an input into a variable called `Names` using the  `Input()` function but can't figure out how.

```
from PySimpleGUI import *

layout = [
    [Text("Name: "),  Input()],
    [Ok()],
    [Text("You Put: "),Output()]
]

window = Window("Just a window", layout)

run = True
while run:
    events, values = window.read()
    name = values[0]
    window[Output].update(value=name)
    if events == WINDOW_CLOSED:
        run = False
window.close()
quit()
```

I've tried using `names = Input()` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you needed to provide your Output in the layout with a key so that it can be indexed in the Window. Not having a matching key is why you're getting a  key error. I made this change to line 7 where you create the layout.

In line 16, `window[Output].update(value=name)`, the key indexing into window needs to match the key of the output field so I updated the line to `window['-output-'].update(value=name)`.

Also it is cleaner to use a `break` statement within an infinite loop than to create the unnecessary `run` variable.

```
from PySimpleGUI import *


layout = [
         [Text("Name: "),  Input()],
         [Ok()],
         [Text("You Put: "),Output(key='-output-')]
]

window = Window("Just a window", layout)


while True:
    events, values = window.read()
    name = values[0]
    window['-output-'].update(value=name)
    if events == WIN_CLOSED:
        break
window.close()
quit()
```